# ADB не видит телефон

Tags: linux, android-studio, adb

Использую операционную систему `Kali Linux`.
Пытался подключить телефон к `Android Studio` и к `ADB` напрямую.
Режим отладки через USB включил.
Вот скрины из `Android Studio`:

Android Studio видит телефон, однако ADB его видеть не хочет:
[image]

Вот сеанс работы с `adb`:

```
user@kali:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached

user@kali:~$ adb kill-server 
user@kali:~$ adb start-server 
user@kali:~$ adb devices 
List of devices attached

user@kali:~$ adb kill-server 
user@kali:~$ adb start-server 
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
user@kali:~$ adb devices 
List of devices attached

user@kali:~$
```

`lsusb` устройство видит.

Пробовал модифицировать файл `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`, ещё что-то пробовал, но так ничего и не добился.

Comment: На устройстве включена отладка и передача файлов? Что выведет sudo adb devices?

Comment: И отладка, и передача включены. С `sudo` всё то же самое.

Comment: Может сам телефон не поддерживает отладку? более того, телефоны давно уже спрашивают " а вы точно хотите отлаживать этот телефон?"

Comment: @KoVadim не, при появлении такого заброса устройство будет отображаться в adb devices как неавторизованное

Comment: у меня не отображался в первый раз. Пришлось потыкать пару раз usb, потом заработало.

Comment: @KoVadim я проверил с другим телефоном. Там всё работает. Почему первый телефон может не работать?

Comment: возможно проблема в самом телефоне. Я бы проверил этот телефон на другом компьютере.

Comment: @KoVadim проверил на другом компьютере на винде, там телефон тоже не видится.

Comment: либо Ваш телефон так не умеет (хорошо бы поискать по его модели в интренете, что люди пишут), либо его недонастроили. Либо это не совсем андроид:) когда то были китайские телефоны, которые выглядят как большой красивый андроид, а в середине начинка от старого, с поддержкой j2me

Comment: @KoVadim прочитал, что нужно включить настройку `USB tethering`, но у меня её в принципе нет. Телефон `LG Q7`, кстати.

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь, что USB tethering может в этом помочь, но мало чего. С другой стороны, то, что на телефоне написано LG Q7, ещё не значит, что это он и есть:)) Маркет работает? приложение можно с него поставить?

Comment: @KoVadim всё работает прекрасно. Только я не понял, что значит "поставить приложение с телефона".

Comment: а я такого не писал. я писал "можно ли поставить с маркета приложение"

Comment: @KoVadim всё можно. Нормальный смартфон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что у меня подключение USB было настроено на "Передача файлов". Я сменил его на "Зарядка", и ADB увидел телефон.